# Shipping methods are not showing after saveBilling method

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on checkout shipping methods but I am not getting what's wrong in configuration that shipping methods are not showing at all at checkout after saveBilling method calls it returns null in shipping methods.Here is a site link www.posmogo.com